# How to getting acquired frames at full speed ? - Image Event Listener does not seem to be executing after every event

Tags: event-listener, dm-script

My goal is to read out 1 pixel from the GIF camera in VIEW mode (live acquisition) and save it to a file every time the data is updated. The camera is ostensibly updating every 0.0001 seconds, because this is the minimum acquisition time Digital Micrograph lets me select in VIEW mode for this camera.

I can attach an Image Event Listener to the live image of the camera, with the message map (`messagemap = "data_changed:MyFunctiontoExecute"`), and MyFunctiontoExecute is being successfully ran, giving me a file with numerous pixel values.

However, if I let this event listener run for a second, I only obtain close to 100 pixel values, when I was expecting closer 10,000 (if the live image is being updated every 0.0001 seconds).

Is this because the Live image is not updated as quickly I think?

Comment: This might actually be more a hardware than a coding question, and the answer will certainly depend on *which* camera you are using. There are many different types of camera and "GIF camera" doesn't specify this - just the location at which the camera is mounted. Having said this, the display-update is *certainly* not done at the insane frame-rates the high-end cameras can achieve, and update-event-listening will not get you the full performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The event-listener certainly is executed at each event.

However, the live-display of a high-speed camera will near-certainly not update at each acquired-frame. It will either perform some sort of cumulative or sampled display. The exact answer will depend on the exact system you are on and configurations that are made.

It should be noted that super-high frame-rates can usually only be achieved by dedicated firmware and optimized systems. It's unlikely that a "general software approach" - in particular of interpreted and non-compiled code - will be able to provide the necessary speed. This type of approach the problem might be doomed from the start.

(Instead, one will likely have to create a buffer and then set-up the system to acquire data directly into the buffer at highest-possible frame rate. This will be coding the camera-acquisition directly)

Comment: Thanks again for the response @BmyGuest! Out of curiosity, how involved would it be to code the camera acquisition directly? Thanks for all your help!