# Fastest way to see which pixel has changed when using a listener

Tags: event-listener, dm-script

I am trying to get EDS spectra on every scanned pixel using STEM.
I am using the `EDSStartAcquisition( 2048, 10,fexposure*2, 1)` command and
I have attached the following simple listener object into the shown 1D spectrum image:

```
string messagemap = "data_value_changed:MyImageAction"  
    Class MyListenerClass1
    {
    String event_desc;

    MyListenerClass1(Object self); //Result("\n");
    ~MyListenerClass1(Object self);// Result("\n");
    
        
        Void MyImageAction(Object self, Number e_fl, Image Img)
        {   
        ImageGetEventMap().DeconstructEventFlags( e_fl, event_desc )
        Result(GetTime(1)+": Image message : " + event_desc + " 0x" + Binary(e_fl) + "\n" ) 
        }
    }

ListenerID1 = EDSIm.ImageAddEventListener( Listener1, messagemap)
```

Since speed is the issue here, I figured to try the continuous mode of the EDS acquisition. But then I would need to listen which counts belong to each scanned pixel. The following topic ([How to getting acquired frames at full speed ? - Image Event Listener does not seem to be executing after every event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56162507/1094536)) shows how to listen to the last pixel change of an image. But what would be the fastest way to directly see which slice of the 1D spectrum has changed on every event? Without going through every slice...

thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm slightly confused by your post. Are you running a Digiscan STEM Scan or a SpectrumImage scan while you want to simultaneously acquire EDS? In any case - unless you are using software-synchronized spectrum-imaging, the display-updates of both STEM or SI image will not be synchronous to the actual beam position.

Comment: Can you explain in what way your intended experiment differs from a regular STEM SI EDX experiment?

Comment: I am using Digiscan STEM while running my own 4D STEM program. I have my own code for the raster scanning. I try not to use SI plugin since  I cannot synchronize it with the CCD camera acquisition and I dont want to be dependent on the SI plugin.

Comment: If you are using your own raster scanning, then your are *not* using a Digiscan acquistion? This confuses me. Because you asked about the regular STEM image display updates. But as said before, the time when the image updates does not correlate to beam position and depends on scanning speed. Image updates happen in "chunks" not on a pixel by pixel basis (unless very slow scanning). I also don't quite what you mean by "which slice of the 1D spectrum has changed" when you are doing a 2D raster scan.

Comment: ...or was your question which channel in the cummulative EDS spectrum has changed on an update of the EDS spectrum? In which case: No direct way to find out, except of computing the difference of the "new" from the "previous" spectrum and analysing that.

Comment: Thanks Bmy.
I am using the DigiScan function DSsetbeamposition() pixel by pixel. But within the SDK side using the command 
GatanPlugIn::gDigitalMicrographInterface.CallFunction(__sFunction.get_ptr(), 1, params, __sSignature);

Not really sure if this is faster. 
"Difference of the "new" from the "previous"" , this is what I am using now. Have to check if this yields correct results...

Comment: Ok, this is then very similar to this publication from [Sader et al.](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ultramic.2010.01.012), right? The main issue with placing the beam like this is positioning precission. If you're scanning a non-regular pattern, don't assume the beam is only where you nominally think it is, in particular when scanning fast. There is reason that "regular scans" use ramps and flyback.

Comment: I've put an answer, so that we can conclude this thread, unless you have more questions. Which reminds me of a StackOverflow-netiquette issue: Can I ask you to "accept" answers of (all) your questions by clicking the checkbox under the voting arrows of the answer that fits? (If any). This will not only earn you reputation points on site, but also helps to find "open" vs. "closed" questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An images' *data_value_changed* is fired whenever a) an image locker (the object that ensures there is single access to the memory) is released, or b) a specific update-call is made in the code.

As such, when a cumulative EDS spectrum is acquired, the whole array gets "locked", then modified (on one or more positions) and then 'updated'. There is no specific information carried on where the array was modified.

Therefore, the only way to find out where the spectrum changed is by comparing a copy of the "before" with the "now" - which is not super efficient.