# Reading in multiple STEM signals into multiple datacubes

Tags: dm-script

I've written a through focus STEM acquisition script that reads in an image using the `DSAcquire` function, where I specify the signal to be read in with `DSAcquireData(img, signalindex, etc.)`.

The nice thing about the above is that I can read in the image without it appearing on screen, copy it into a datacube, and then acquire the next one in the series, etc.

If I want to use two signals instead of one (eg HAADF and BF), it looks like the only way to do this is to use `DSStartAcquisition` after setting the digiscan parameters?

How should I go about copying signals into two preallocated image stacks (`stack1`, `stack2`)? Preferably without tens of images cluttering the screen (but ideally with some measure of progress?)

Comment: Presumably you want a continuous acquisition, or are you asking for a loop of indivial calls?

Comment: I'd prefer a continuous acquisition, but I would be changing focus throughout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this - by iterating over x individual acquisitions is a straight forward expansion of the F1 help examples:

[image]

```c
// Acquire 2 signals simultaneously, e.g. HAADF and BF detector


number paramID
number width    = 512 // pixel
number height   = 512 // pixel
number rotation = 0   // degree
number pixelTime= 2   // microseconds
number lSynch   = 1   // activated
paramID = DSCreateParameters( width, height, rotation, pixelTime, lSynch )

number signalIndex, dataType, selected, imageID
signalIndex = 0
dataType    = 2 // 2 byte data
selected    = 1 // acquire this signal

image img1 := IntegerImage( "Signal 1", dataType, 0, width, height )
img1.ShowImage()
imageID     = img1.ImageGetID() // use displayed image
DSSetParametersSignal( paramID, signalIndex, dataType, selected, imageID )

signalIndex = 1
dataType    = 2 // 2 byte data
selected    = 1 // acquire this signal

image img2 := IntegerImage( "Signal 1", dataType, 0, width, height )
img2.Showimage()
imageID     = img2.ImageGetID() // use displayed image
DSSetParametersSignal( paramID, signalIndex, dataType, selected, imageID )

number continuous  = 0 // 0 = single frame, 1 = continuous
number synchronous = 1 // 0 = return immediately, 1 = return when finished

// Create stack to copy data to
number nplanes = 10
image stack1 := img1.ImageClone()
stack1.ImageResize(3,width,height,nplanes)
stack1.SetName("Signal 1 (stack)")
stack1.ShowImage()

image stack2 := img2.ImageClone()
stack2.ImageResize(3,width,height,nplanes)
stack2.SetName("Signal 2 (stack)")
stack2.ShowImage()

//Quickly arrange image
EGUPerformActionWithAllShownImages("arrange")

// Iterated acquisition
for( number i=0; i<nPlanes; i++ )
{
    DSStartAcquisition( paramID, continuous, synchronous )
    // Copy data
    stack1.slice2(0,0,i, 0,width,1, 1,height,1) = img1
    stack2.slice2(0,0,i, 0,width,1, 1,height,1) = img2
}
DSDeleteParameters( paramID ) // remove parameters from memory
```

---

However, this will restart a new Digiscan acquisition at each frame. You might want to prefer doing this with a continuous acquisition and an image listener instead.

For this, you would most likely hook up an image-listener as described in the F1 help here:
[image]

The Digiscan acquisition - depending on the speed - will update the image several times per frame, so you will need some check if it's end-of-frame.

One way to do this would be to use a *data_value_changed* event and then check if the last pixel in the image has changed value. Another option would be to use the *tags_changed* event, as apparently the tags of the acquisition image are update once per frame. Both options have some potential issues, though.

See also this very relevant recent question on this topic: [Fastest way to see which pixel has changed when using a listener](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63632018/1302888)

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a read about using the listener as well. Using the image ID was something that I hadn't thought of! Smart!

Comment: @TomNorway You might also want to check-out the [plugins here](http://dmscript.tavernmaker.de/), in particular the *DigiScan Stack Acquisition* and the *StackBuilder (on image update)*.

Comment: I'm now trying to read out in continuous mode, change focus and perform an image operation (run a filter over the image and find the `max` of it as a function of focus). Does running in continuous mode require threading in order to stop the acquisition gracefully? If not, do I still require threading if I want to perform the mentioned focus change and image operations? Logic says yes, but I noticed you didn't mention it.

Comment: @TomNorway If you run in continuous mode it is essentially like if you would have a "search" view running. Changing microscope focus does not impact on the scanning (but you will get mid-frame image contrast changes, so likely garbage for a frame or two unless you wait for a fresh one to come in.) Running an image filter would need to be run on a *copy* of that image (taken at frame complete) and not on the image used for constant readout.

Comment: What about the threading aspect? Does the continuous mode run in its own thread under the hood, which lets the script progress to letting my change focus? Or do I need to run the DSAcquisition in its own thread? Additionally, do you know if `synchrononous=1` during continuous readout updates the entire frame simultanously? That would let me not worry about triggering specifically on the *last pixel*. I can't check right now because someone is using our microscope :p

Comment: Yes, the hardware runs on its own thread and should not interfere with the script. Synchronous TRUE means the script will hold until the acqusition is stopped. Data updates are always section wise and not tied to end-of-frame.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the precise answers and super quick response!